# webkit image rotation with javascript/jquery, no style sheet

Tags: jquery, rotation

I have a button that I'd like to rotate 45 degrees when it's clicked, and when it's clicked again it rotates 45 degrees again.  I can't use a style sheet and had been looking at this solution because it used only JavaScript http://jsfiddle.net/7b4VZ/3/ and was wondering if it could be set up as a class, again only using JavaScript that I can then set up as a toggle class with jQuery?

Code of fiddle:

```
var img = document.images[0];
img.style.setProperty("-webkit-transition", "left 2s linear");
var slide = function(){
img.style.setProperty("left", "200px");
setTimeout(function(){
    img.style.setProperty("left", "0px");
    setTimeout(slide,2000);    
},2000);
}

slide();​
```

Comment: Do you want to animate the rotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS transforms for the rotation: http://jsfiddle.net/antishok/7b4VZ/60/

Comment: oo, that's good, two things, is it possible to have it so it doesn't actually slide, and just waits to be clicked, and is it possible to have it so instead of rotating back it rotates fowards again when it gets clicked again?  The other thing I was trying to add into this was I was trying to slide toggle a paragraph as well     $("#effects_of_yoga_info").click(function () {
      $("p#effects_of_yoga_text").slideToggle("fast");
    });

Comment: so would it be possible to have the rotation of that button and teh slidetoggle of the paragraph happen at the same time, and then which the button is clicked again, toggleslide closed and rotate forward again at the same time?

Comment: If you don't want it to slide, don't use the sliding code. If you want it to keep adding 45 instead of toggling between 0 and 45, just do that. http://jsfiddle.net/antishok/7b4VZ/61/  As for the other things, they aren't related to your posted question. Try some more and if you can't get it working, post a new question with a new testcase.